# How to use variable while creating HotString in my script (AutoHotKey)

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a hotstring which needs to take a variable value as it's key

Example:

```
b := "btw"
::%b%::
    Send, By the way
    return
```

When i type btw and space, it must replace the text with "By the way"

Answer (score 2):

Per the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm): "[v1.1.28+]: Hotstrings can be created dynamically by means of the Hotstring function, which can also modify, disable, or enable the script's existing hotstrings individually."

Untested example:

```
b := "::btw"
Hotstring(b,"by the way")
```

Comment: .. and for older versions, there is a library which can do that I think